# Check existence of belongsTo() relation in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model named List that represents a navigation tree. I should be able to navigate into a child list, and then hit the back button to go back up to the parent list.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),

  children: DS.hasMany('list', { inverse: 'parent' }),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('list', { inverse: 'children' }) 
});
```

I determine the "root" level list in my routes file by looking for the list that has no parents.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('list').then(function(lists){
      return lists.filter(function(list){
        if(Ember.isEmpty(list.get('parent').get('content'))) {
          return true;
        } 
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }).get('firstObject');
    }); 
  }
});
```

There's a number of things I feel like are wrong about my implementation, even though it works on the initial page load.

- `Ember.isEmpty(list.get('parent').get('content'))` completely seems like the wrong way to check for the existence of the parent relationship.
- I feel like I may not be filtering the entire list collection correctly. I'm intentionally calling the index API request so that all lists are loaded, but when I navigate to a child list and hit the back button, the XHR request is made a second time!
- Building on top of that, the filtering *only* works for the initial page load. If I go down into a list and then hit the back button, the child list persists on the page (no errors or anything!).

What is the *right* way to check existence of the parent relationship?

Also, what's the *right* way to filter the entire list to find one record?

Is my ignorance what's causing issues with the back button?

Comment: Ember.isEmpty(list.get('parent').get('content')) You could go ParentExists: Ember.computed.notEmpty(xx)

Answer (score 4):

Since Ember Data 2.5 it's possible to use the new References API to check for the existence of a belongsTo relation.
You just have to check if obj.belongsTo('relation').id() is null.

In the OP's example, it would become:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('list').then(function(lists){
      return lists.filter(function(list){
        if(list.belongsTo('parent').id() === null) {
          return true;
        } 
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }).get('firstObject');
    }); 
  }
});
```

It's also possible to check if the relation has already been loaded, load it manually, reload it and some other cool things.
Check the [release notes](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no related record then the corresponding property should be `null`. So you can simplify your code like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('list').then(function(lists){
      return lists.findBy('parent', null);
    }); 
  }

});
```

If you need to cache the model data to avoid hitting the server, you can also add:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  parentModel: null,

  model(){
    var _this = this;  
    return this.parentModel || this.store.findAll('list').then(function(lists){
      _this.parentModel = lists.findBy('parent', null);
      return _this.parentModel;
    }); 
  }

});
```